# How can I add divs to an array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, dom-manipulation

I would like to create several `div`s with the same options like color, width, height, etc.

I would like to add all of these divs to an array, but I need to do this dynamically.

My current code:

```
var ArrayInfo = []; 

    do { 
    var InfoDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    InfoDiv.id = 'Info_Div'; 
    InfoDiv.className = 'Info_Div'; 
    InfoDiv.style.width = "100px"; 
    InfoDiv.style.height = "30px"; 
    InfoDiv.style.display = "inline-block"; 

    ArrayInfo.push(InfoDiv);

}while(i < x);
```

`x` can be a very very large number.

1. Is this the right way to add div a to an array?
2. How can I write text into the elements of an array?

I tried this:

```
ArrayInfo[i].innerHTML = "something";
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: All these divs have the same id `Info_Div`, this is illegal HTML. Please elaborate on didn't worked.

Comment: Where does `i` change? What are the values of `i` and `x`? If `i` never changes the loop will execute 1 or infinite times. Consider a `for` loop instead.

Comment: `ArrayInfo[i].innerHTML = "something";` <-- well is `i` greater than the length of the array???

Answer (score 1):

You never increment `i`, so your loop will never end.

Second, you never actually *add* any of the `div`s to the document -- creating them doesn't do that for you.

And as noted in the comments, you can't use the same `id` over and over.

```js
var ArrayInfo = [];

var x = 10;

var ctr = document.getElementById('ctr');

for (var i = 0; i < x; ++i) {

  var InfoDiv = document.createElement('div');
  InfoDiv.id = 'Info_Div' + i;
  InfoDiv.className = 'Info_Div';
  InfoDiv.style.width = "100px";
  InfoDiv.style.height = "30px";
  InfoDiv.style.display = "inline-block";

  ArrayInfo.push(InfoDiv);

  ctr.appendChild(InfoDiv);
}

for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {

  ArrayInfo[i].innerHTML = "div " + i;
}
```

```html
<div id=ctr></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique! Considering adding a number to the end of each `Info_Div` to uniquely identify it.

Also consider using a `for loop` instead of a `do while` loop.

The convention for JavaScript variables is lowerCamelCase. So we should fix that as well.

In your code, the divs were added to the array but not to the document. If you wanted to add them to the DOM, you would have to add `document.body.appendChild`.

Your code would look more like this.

```
var arrayInfo = []; 
var x = 5;                                           // Or whatever value it is

for (var i = 1; i < x; i++) { 
    var infoDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    infoDiv.id = 'Info_Div' + i; 
    infoDiv.className = 'Info_Div'; 
    infoDiv.style.width = "100px"; 
    infoDiv.style.height = "30px"; 
    infoDiv.style.display = "inline-block"; 

    arrayInfo.push(infoDiv);
    arrayInfo[i].innerHTML = "div " + i;
    document.body.appendChild(infoDiv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried all of them so I can fixed the problem. I can't decide which answer is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using do...while. I'd also avoid creating a new div on every loop. Instantiate once, then clone (it's faster).

```
var InfoDiv = document.createElement('div');
InfoDiv.id = 'Info_Div';
InfoDiv.className = 'Info_Div';
InfoDiv.style.width = "100px";
InfoDiv.style.height = "30px";
InfoDiv.style.display = "inline-block";

var ArrayInfo = [];
for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var div = InfoDiv.cloneNode(true);
    div.id += i; // Add number to id
    ArrayInfo.push(div);
}
```